# Accessing variable in a function without calling it in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

Here is my code

```
def function():
  global x
  x = 5

print (x)
```

How can I access the local variable `x` inside the function without calling the function itself?

Comment: You can't. Until you've called the function, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ohhhh. Thats It! Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. A variable inside a function will only be after the function is called, else it is non-existent. Look into how local[local,non-local, and global variables](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables) work.

```
  def function():
  global x
  x = 5
  print(x)

function()
```

else you should just put x outside the `function()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just put x = 5 outside the function